# Relacionamento BelongsToMany - Sequelize

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express.js, sequelize-js

Olá, estou com um problema na listagem de registros com associação belongsToMany utilizando sequelize + nodejs.

Tenho as tabelas **developers** e **technologies**.
A relação entre elas é many to many. Para criar a relação, utilizei uma tabela pivô chamada **developers_technologies**.

Abaixo tem um gist com o código de: Models (developers, techonologies), migration (developers_technologies) e controller de Developers.

https://gist.github.com/fredarend/85ff60fca70643d80301b499e871c4a6

O código do Index do controller Developer é esse:

```
async index(req, res) {
const developers = await Developer.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
  include: [
    {
      model: Technologies,
      as: 'technologies',
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
      through: { attributes: [] },
    },
  ],
});

return res.json(developers);}
```

O retorno que estou recebendo é:

```
[
    {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "Jon Doe",
        "email": "jondoe@gmail.com",
        "age": 27,
        "url_linkedin": "http://asdasdasd",
        "technologies": []
    }
]
```

Gostaria de saber por qual motivo não estou recebendo as technologies atreladas ao developer, sendo que existe a tabela developers_technologies no banco de dados está populada e as relações nos models estão ok.

Atenciosamente,

Answer (score -2):

olha falto a associacao (association)

faz assim :

```
async index(req, res) {
  const developers = await Developer.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
    include: [
      {
        model: Technologies,
        as: 'technologies',
        association: 'nome da associacao', attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        through: { attributes: [] },
      },
    ],
  });

  return res.json(developers);
}
```